# Does a process with CAP_NET_RAW set still run in user-space?

Tags: sockets, linux-capabilities, userspace

If I execute

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep /path/prog
```

and prog is a program which open a raw socket, can be prog still considered to run in user-space? How can I check it?

Comment: programs **always** run in user-space (whatever the privileges). Except if you develop a kernel module or the kernel itself.